# Manual kernel update: System won't boot new kernel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, kernel, ubuntu-16.04

In response to Dirty COW, I installed the 4.4.0-45 kernel as described in the answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839919/what-is-dirty-cow-bug-that-allows-local-user-to-gain-administrative-access) question.

Output from `dpkg -l | grep '4\.4\.0-45'`

```
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-45                                      4.4.0-45.66                                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic                              4.4.0-45.66                                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic                                4.4.0-45.66                                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic                          4.4.0-45.66                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                                        4.4.0-45.66                                          amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
```

clearly shows it is installed and `update-grub` detects it

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done
```

but even after rebooting the machine for the umpteenth time `uname -r` still gives me

```
4.2.0-38-generic
```

I want to know what step I missed that keeps the system from booting the new kernel.

Comment: Is it listed in the GRUB configuration? Alternatively, what's in the GRUB menu when you start up?

Comment: @l0b0 Thanks. It kept the old kernel as default for some reason, and as this is a machine mainly managed using SSH, I didn't notice. But still, even if I reboot with `GRUB_DEFAULT='gnulinux-advanced-f0724a95-d885-4cec-b74c-635d61f32c73>gnulinux-4.4.0-45-generic-advanced-f0724a95-d885-4cec-b74c-635d61f32c73'` (the name gathered from the grub config file, it still boots into the old kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install a new kernel version to patch the dirty cow vulnerability just  [enable  the Canonical Livepatch Service on your Ubuntu](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2016-October/000214.html)

> Kernel live patching enables runtime correction of critical security
>   issues in your kernel without rebooting. It’s the best way to ensure
>   that machines are safe at the kernel level, while guaranteeing uptime,
>   especially for container hosts where a single machine may be running
>   thousands of different workloads.
>
> (1) Go to https://ubuntu.com/livepatch and retrieve your livepatch
>   token, for example: d3b07384d213edec49eaa6238ad5ff00
>
> (2) Install the livepatch snap, like this:
>      $ sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
>
> (3) Enable your account with the token from step 1
>
> $ sudo canonical-livepatch enable d3b07384d113edec49eaa6238ad5ff00
>
> That’s it.  You’re up and running!  You can check your status at any 
>   time with:
>
> $ canonical-livepatch status
>      kernel: 4.4.0-38.57-generic
>      fully-patched: true
>      version: "12.2"
>
> Now your kernel will remain securely patched, and you can reboot when
>   it’s convenient for you.

Or by runing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: There is something weird happening when I try to enable it. No matter if I use regular `sudo` or login as root with `sudo -i` to gain privilege, the enable command fails with "Permission denied" on some file.

Comment: As root or  allow `sudo` to execute root commands

Comment: `~# canonical-livepatch enable **** ;
cannot bind-mount the mount namespace file /proc/3070/ns/mnt -> canonical-livepatch.mnt. errmsg: Permission denied
support process for mount namespace capture exited abnormally` This is the output I get when I run it as root. Sorry for bad formatting, I'm on my phone at the moment.

Comment: take a look here http://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/10/31/dirty-cow-was-livepatched-in-ubuntu-within-hours-of-publication/

Answer (score -1):

Better is You boot from old kernel 
And delete all new kernel files from `/boot` 
Then 
`update-grub` 
After it you can set default old kernel 
Then 
`sudo aptitude safe-upgrade`
Hope it will help 
And if not 
Download boot-repair and fix some issue 
I like manually but it will risky for new person

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you [edit] and explain *why* this suggestion works, rather than what OP did (as they did indeed run `update-grub`)?